# BS4 for find any title value

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I Have Code sample Bellow:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


html = '''
<div _ngcontent-vnr-c286="" class="nui-text-widget nui-widget__header__content-title ng-tns-c286-4 ng-star-inserted" title="SRV-VMWARE-02" style=""> SRV-VMWARE-02 </div>
<div _ngcontent-vnr-c286="" class="nui-text-widget nui-widget__header__content-title ng-tns-c286-16 ng-star-inserted" title="SRV-VMWARE-01" style=""> SRV-VMWARE-01 </div>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for d in soup:
    test = d.find("div", {"title": "any_title"}).getText()
    print(test)
```

My question is there a way to search any value on "title=", without us having to specifically define the value of title , example "title='SRV-VMWARE-02'" ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually want title attributes containing a specific string? E.g. title="SRV-VMWARE-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<div _ngcontent-vnr-c286="" class="nui-text-widget nui-widget__header__content-title ng-tns-c286-4 ng-star-inserted" title="SRV-VMWARE-02" style=""> SRV-VMWARE-02 </div>
<div _ngcontent-vnr-c286="" class="nui-text-widget nui-widget__header__content-title ng-tns-c286-16 ng-star-inserted" title="SRV-VMWARE-01" style=""> SRV-VMWARE-01 </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
test = soup.findAll("div", {"title": True})
for t in test:
    print(t.getText())
```

By passing in `True`, you can pull any element that has the attribute `title`. Use `False` to pull any element without the attribute.

Additionaly, if you want to pull elements based on a partial value, BeautifulSoup supports Regex

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
test = soup.findAll("div", {"title": re.compile('SRV-VMWARE')})
for t in test:
    print(t.getText())
```